# Asher Yatzar after Seminal Emission

Tags: halacha, asher-yatzar

I've been wondering this for a while: does one say Asher Yatzar after he ejaculates (whether in the context of permissible relations, or any other cases)?

I ask this because some Rishonim seem to understand one function of seminal emissions to be the body's way of removing material from it as necessary (see [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ibn_Ezra/Vayikra/18.20#t1e0n6) for example).

Comment: It would be hard to call zerah waste,zerah has potential life,so dont aee how that fits with asher yatzar

Comment: @sam I don't see the word "waste" in _Asher yatzar_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/209669) quotes the *Kaf Hachaim* ([OC 240:28](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14420&st=&pgnum=376)), who says that one shouldn't say *Asher Yatzar* after marital relations, however, it is best to relieve oneself afterwards and when saying *Asher Yatzar* for that, to have in mind to include this as well. The article concludes that all the more so after a forbidden ejaculation one should not say *Asher Yatzar*.

Comment: ...although it gives no logical explanation as to why that should be "all the more so" (in the case of forbidden ejaculation).  But thanks for the Kaf Hachaim, accepted.  I'd also love if someone would give a reason or something like that.

Comment: It's not obvious one Asher Yatzar can cover two events.

Comment: @DoubleAA So, if one defecates and urinates at the same time / rest room trip, one should say *Asher Yatzar* twice?

Comment: @DanF No that's one event, but if you use the restroom and forget to say Asher Yatzar and use the restroom again an hour later then according to some you have to say it twice.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ploni for starting this off.  Shu"t Halachos Ketanos 1:137 (quoted in [Pachad Yitzchak (Lampronti) Erech Tashmish](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wKQ0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PP371&lpg=PP371&dq=%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9&source=bl&ots=TfV451aI8Y&sig=6uA3RSq1a4y7jyBI_GlQhwilRpY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinq6KKnf_ZAhUh0YMKHd1ZCUcQ6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9&f=false), as well as the Kaf Hachaim above) gives two possible reasons for not saying it:

> אם בדרך הטבע אין חוש המישוש חרפה לבע"ח אלא שהנהיגוהו במקומות האסורים **וכיון שרוב ביאות שבעולם הם באיסור ובאפקירותא אפשר שלא רצו לתקן ברכה על זה**. **א"נ משום שהוא מזיק לגוף כמ"ש הרמב"ם ז"ל (בפ"ד מדיעות) ואין מברכין על הקלקלה** ואפשר שאם יהיה בשעת רצון ושצריך לדבר ויטהר עצמו וינקה היטב במקום קדוש שיברך ועתב"ט:

In short:

1. Most relations that take place are prohibited, and therefore Chazal did not want us to make a Beracha on them
2. It is harmful to the body.

Therefore, the Halachos Ketanos concludes that it is possible that if one feels like he needs to be Motzi Zera, and the relations are done properly, at the right time, and he is clean and in a proper place, he should make an Asher Yatzar.  He also later suggests the opinion quoted above, that one should use the bathroom and have both emptyings in mind.  This is also suggested in [this Chabad article](http://abc770.org/article_node_2428/).

(Although I'm not really sure that I understand either answer, I would propose that Chazal did not institute an Asher Yatzar on this because it will often be a while until someone is clean and in a proper place to make such a Beracha.)

Rabbi Gamliel Rabinowitz [here](http://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=13688) (p. 59) brings a few other suggestions in addition to a very long summary of the above and other sources.

1. If it would be blocked up, you would still be able to survive.
2. Originally since Tevilas Ezra was required, one could not make the Beracha until after Tevilah, and it never became required by Chazal since then.

Comment: What does ועתב"ט stand for

Comment: @robev ועליו (ועליהם) תבא ברכת טוב. see https://www.google.ca/search?safe=active&client=opera&hs=R9Q&ei=Vhm1WpHPEMjM_Ab37LGQDg&q=ועליו+תבא+ברכת+טוב&oq=ועליו+תבא+ברכת+טוב&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1l3.39787.39787.0.40031.1.1.0.0.0.0.193.193.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.191....0.ZUx81qVLJHc